# Prove that a set is denumerable if and only if the set is equipotent to any of its infinite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have shown the 'only if' part. Can anyone give a nice proof for 'if' part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "if" part: Let $S$ be equipotent to each of its infinite subsets. Either $S$ is finite in which case we're done or $S$ is infinite. Let's now consider the case where $S$ is infinite: Then $|S| \geq |N|$. Therefore there is an injective function $f: N \rightarrow S$ and $f(N) \subset S$ and $f(N)$ is infinite and $|f(N)| = |N|$. But then because $S$ is equipotent to $f(N)$ it follows that $|S| = |f(N)| = |N|$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You omitted the proof of $|S|\ge|N|$ which, while not difficult, is the only nontrivial step in the proof.

Comment: @bof. Without AC we can show that if S is not  Tarski-finite and if S is equipotent to any of its Tarski-infinite subsets then S is Dedekind-infinite, from which, S has a countably infinite subset.

Answer (score 0):

$\Longrightarrow$: Let $A$ be a denumerable set. Then $|A|=\aleph_0$; let $B$ be an infinite subset of $A$.

Since $B\subseteq A$, $|B|\leq|A|=\aleph_0$. Since $B$ is infinite, $|A|=\aleph_0\leq|B|$

By the *Cantor-Bernstein* theorem, $B$ has the cardinality of $A$

$\Longleftarrow$: There are several cases:

- $A$ is finite

Then obviously none of its proper subsets will be equipotent with $A$

- $A$ is infinite

Then $A$ is not empty, say $a_0\in A$. Then the proper subset $B=A\setminus\{a_0\}$ is equipotent with $A$ by hypothesis; let $f:A\longrightarrow B$ be an bijective function from $A$ onto $B$. Let $g:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow A$ be the sequence defined by recursion:

$$\begin{cases}
  g(0)=a_0\\
  g(n+1)=f(g(n))
\end{cases}$$

We will prove that $g$ is injective. so $\text{Im}(g)$ will be a countably infinite subset of $A$.

Suppose that $g$ is not injective. Then there exists a couple of natural numbers $m,n$ with $m<n$ such that $g(m)=g(n)$. We have that the set

$$\mathcal{N}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\;|\;\text{there exists }m>n\text{ such that }g(m)=g(n)\}$$

is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $n_0$ be its first element.

- In first place, $n_0\not=0$, because $g(0)=a_0,\;a_0\not\in B$, and if $n>0,\;g(n)\in\text{Im}(f)=B$
- Since $n_0>0$, we have that if $m\in\mathcal{N}$ is such that $m>n_0$ and $g(n_0)=g(m)$, then

$$g(n_0)=f(g(n_0-1))=f(g(m-1))=g(m)$$

And, since $f$ is injective

$$g(n_0-1)=g(m-1)$$

Which contradicts the choice of $n_0$ as the first element of $\mathcal{N}$